# How to go back to a certain point in batch

Tags: batch-file

Now i know how to create what i call tags

for example `:startgame`

And i know `goto :startgame` or in some occasions just `goto startgame` will take you back however

when i am doing `if %selector% == r goto :Start_1`
it just simply will close the batch file and i have tried with caps and without and without the `:`.

Now don't just be rude and call me ignorant i know basic batch

This is my start code

```
:Start_1
echo **************************************************
echo ************App selector by michaelukz************
echo **************************************************
echo **************************************************
echo To select an app press any button.
pause
```

This is the code i am trying to get to work

```
:Selected
echo You have selected your file.
echo If you wish to choose another file press R.
echo If you wish to close a program / file press C.
echo If you wish to close press any button.
SET /P"selected=Input letter here:      "
if %selector% == r goto :Start_1
if %selector% == R goto :Start_1
if %selector% == c start taskmgr.exe
if %selector% == C start taskmgr.exe
if not timeout /T 3
echo Going to close menu
goto Closemenu
```

all the rest works except `goto start_1`.

Please help but don't be ignorrant - i have seen other people on here acting snarky as such.

Comment: Well - @aphoria has it sorted. Note that your `if not timeout /t...` won't work because the syntax of `if` requires a comparison operator `if [not] something compare-op something_else dothis` Snarky? Not in the batch area. Other areas, I'll grant you. Not batch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at `CHOICE` command, also you misspelled `selector` var name in `SET /P`

```
@echo off
:Start_1
echo **************************************************
echo ************App selector by michaelukz************
echo **************************************************
echo **************************************************
echo To select an app press any button.

:Selected
echo You have selected your file.
echo If you wish to choose another file press R.
echo If you wish to close a program / file press C.
echo If you wish to close press Q.
choice /C RCQ /N /M "Choose wisely [R,C,Q]" /D Q /T 30
goto action%errorlevel%

:action1
echo option R
goto start_1
goto selected

:action2
echo option C
start taskmgr.exe
goto selected

:action3
echo option Q
goto closemenu


goto Closemenu
```

Answer (score 3):

A few things...

1. What you are calling tags are usually referred to as labels.
2. In your code, you are setting a variable called `selected` in this line `SET /P"selected=Input letter here:      "`, but in your `IF` statements you are comparing to a variable called `selector`.
3. The line `if not timeout /T 3` will not work. As @Magoo pointed out in a comment to the question, the syntax of `if` requires a comparison operator `if [not] something compare-op something_else dothis`.